# Service broker error: delete your existing Lite plan instance

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have received this message:

> Service broker error: You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan.

I do not know how to delete the previous Lite plan instance, can someone help please?

Answer (score 5):

This error comes if you have already lite plan instance, so you needs to delete existing to create a new one.

Go to the below address, You would found your existing lite instance list.

IBM service Resources https://cloud.ibm.com/resources

You need to remove all existing service's, because in **LITE** plan you can have one lite instance at a time only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [IBM Cloud dashboard](https://console.bluemix.net/) (UI) or the [command line interface (CLI)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/bx_cli.html#bluemix_cli) to check for instances of that service.

In the UI, there is a context menu on each service. Use it to delete the service instance.

With the CLI and within a space, you can use `ibmcloud cf services` to list service. For services in resource groups use `ibmcloud resource service-instances`. Then use either `ibmcloud cf delete-service` or `ibmcloud resource service-instance-delete` to remove that instance.