# IBM Coud: Create Service Watson Studio - Does not show up in resource list- But when create a new one it states it exist

Tags: service, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Error Below:

```
Service broker error: You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan.
```

I have no idea how to work arount this: Any help would be appreciated

I have seen this:
[Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610877/service-broker-error-delete-your-existing-lite-plan-instance)

But makes the assumption that it is in the resource list mine is completely empty

Comment: A the top of the home page https://cloud.ibm.com is a "Search resources and products" search. Tap in "Watson Studio" in there and see if something comes up.

Comment: nothing does- every seems to be zero